# What is the frequency response of binning 2x2 pixels of an image into 1 pixel in software?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform

What is the frequency response of binning 2x2 pixels into 1 pixel in software?
Can the binning introduce aliasing?

Since the Fourier of the 2D boxcar function is a 2D sinc I would intuitively think that the sharp edges of the 2x2 filter would cause ringing in the frequency domain?

Would it not be better to window this filter?
E.g. use a 4x4 filter with low weights along the edge and higher weights inside the 2x2 core?

Consider a greyscale image: $I(x_i,y_j)$
where $0 < i < 2*m$ and $0 < j < 2*n$.

Bin together 2x2 pixels:
$$\begin{align}
I_b(x_I,y_J) =\ & 0.25\ [I(2x_I,2y_J)+I(2x_I+1,2y_J)+ \\ &I(2x_I,2y_J+1)+I(2x_I+1,2y_J+1)]
\end{align} \tag 1$$

where $0 < I < m$ and $0 < J < n$.

The two dimensional frequency of the image before binning: $F(u,v)$.

The two dimensional frequency of the image after binning: $F_b(u,v)$.

What is $$H(u,v)=F(u,v)/F_b(u,v) ?\tag 2 $$

Answer (score 2):

To make sense of this, consider that you are doing *two* operations: 2x2 averaging, as you express in (1), above, and then decimating by 2 in each direction.

The 2x2 averaging is just filtering.  The 2x2 subsampling does, indeed, cause aliasing.

Your (2) is a transfer function, that bears an implicit assumption of a linear *and shift invariant* process.  The 2x2 *averaging* (without subsampling) is shift invariant, and (2) can apply.  Once you've done that averaging, however, the 2x2 subsampling can no longer be expressed as a simple transfer function.

You could recast (1) so that it operates on $x_i$ and $x_j$ (i.e., no subsampling) and find the frequency response; *then* you could apply the effects of aliasing.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Does this mean that there does not exist a general frequency response function? I will have to calculate one per image? Also I do not understand how I can recast (1) so that it operates on i and j indexes. This sounds like a convolution with a filter and I do not think that this is what is happening. The filter is only applied at a subset of (i,j).

Answer (score 2):

Note that cameras have lenses and lenses have a point spread function (PSF) that behaves like a spatial continuous domain lowpass-filter. Depending on aperture, quality of optics and scene/camera movement during the exposure.

Note also that many sensors have an Optical Lowpass Filter (OLPF) that acts like a continuous spatial domain comb filter tuned more or less to have some attenuation relative to pixel pitch.

Note that sensel active sensing area may not be a perfect square of dimensions inverse to the sensel pitch.

Note that color cameras typically have a color filter array (CFA) that repeats some «red»/«green»/«blue» filter pattern, usually the Bayer pattern on top of the monochrome image sensor:

```
R G
G B
```

For color cameras doing binning, the most common CFA seems to be «quad bayer» where the filtering is e.g.:

```
R R G G
R R G G
G G B B
G G B B
```

Notice that this quad Bayer CFA is just a 2x2 «upsampled» regular Bayer CFA. Thus, for a simplistic analysis, a 2x2 binned image from a 48 MP sensor may be expected to have similar properties to a 12 MP sensor of similar dimensions, assuming that olpf is scaled accordingly (which is anyones guess) and that the binning is a simple addition.

The analysis could be as complicated as you care to make it (and the characterisation of components)Or you could assume that it is a 2x2 boxcar prefilter prior to downsampling, with the associated poor frequency-domain suppression of the bands that cannot be reconstructed according to Nyquist.

Comment: There may be other binning schemes out there working on regular Bayer CFAs by combining non-immediate neighbours of the same color. That sounds «fiddly» both from an electronics as well as dsp-analysis PoV

Comment: Are you saying that most likely the image is already low pass filtered so much that 2x2 subsampling does not cause aliasing?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt at Fourier analysis:

Underlying continous image: $I_{cont}(x,y)$.
Introduce comb function:
$$C(x,y)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty} \sum_{l=-\infty}^{l=\infty}\delta(x-k\Delta x) \delta(y-l\Delta y) $$

Original image:
$I = I_{cont}*C(x,y)$

$\mathcal{F}(I)=\mathcal{F}(I_{cont})\mathcal{F}(C)$

Binned image:
$I_b = 0.25I_{cont}*C+0.25I_{cont}*C_{10}+0.25I_{cont}*C_{01}+0.25I_{cont}*C_{11}$

where
$C_{10}=C(x-\Delta x,y)$, $C_{01}=C(x,y-\Delta y)$ and $C_{11}=C(x-\Delta x,y-\Delta y)$

$\mathcal{F}(I_b)=0.25\mathcal{F}(I_{cont})[\mathcal{F}(C)+e^{-i2\pi u\Delta x}\mathcal{F}(C)+e^{-i2\pi v\Delta y}\mathcal{F}(C)+e^{-i2\pi(u\Delta x + v\Delta y)}\mathcal{F}(C)]$

$\mathcal{F}(I_b)=0.25\mathcal{F}(I_{cont})\mathcal{F}(C)[1+e^{-i2\pi u\Delta x}+e^{-i2\pi v\Delta y}+e^{-i2\pi(u\Delta x + v\Delta y)}]$

$H(u,v)=0.25*[1+e^{-i2\pi u\Delta x}+e^{-i2\pi v\Delta y}+e^{-i2\pi(u\Delta x + v\Delta y)}]$